# ZF2 Login Forwarding

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zfcuser

I have a function in a controller, which needs to check whether the user is logged in (I'm using zfcuser module), and if not, show them the login screen.

It is my understanding that I should be running this:

```
return $this->forward()->dispatch('zfcuser', array('action' => 'authenticate'));
```

Unfortunately, this changes the url. I want to show the login screen and allow the user to login without the url changing. By extension this means I will also want to redirect the user back to the same page instead of going to the `/user` page.

How can I achieve both these things?

Comment: I would rather save link to session which user want to access and after successful login redirect to that page.

Comment: I agree with kierzniak. I'd save the route name and params in the session, redirect to login and redirect back to this route information. This obviously won't work with POST requests though.

Comment: You both think it would be better practice to preserve the URL - that's fair enough, but how would I get the login to redirect back? It currently goes to /user once logged in (which is the built-in user's profile page).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I struggled with this myself for the last couple of days. The ZfcUser configuration includes a `use_redirect_parameter_if_present` setting, but the documentation doesn't give any examples on how one might use this. I don't know if my method is solid, but here's what I did to get this working. Note that this method preserves the URL because it uses forward. I'm not sure of another way to do this without using forward.

In your zfcuser configuration file, go ahead and set that `use_redirect_parameter_if_present` setting to `true`. This causes ZfcUser's login action to look for a `redirect` parameter in the request. It uses this to return the user to the specified location after successful authentication.

Then, in the controller where I want to ensure the user is logged in, I have:

```
if (!$this->zfcUserAuthentication()->hasIdentity()) {

    // Build the redirect URL using the route to which we want
    // the user returned.
    $redirect = $this->url()->fromRoute('your route', array(
        'optional-route-param' => 1234
    ));

    // Set the redirect URL in the request so that ZfcUser can
    // pick it up. This is the key.
    $this->getRequest()->getQuery()->set('redirect', $redirect);

    // Use ZfcUser's login action rather than its authentication
    // action.
    return $this->forward()->dispatch('zfcuser', array(
        'action' => 'login'
    ));
}
```

I hope that helps. If you have issues getting this working, you may need to post some code.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to build the redirect variable from $this->getRequest()->getRequestUri(), which suited my purposes.